# Fatal error in magento 2 compilation

Tags: error, magento-2.1.3, fatal-error, compilation, place-order

After running compilation code

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

I'am getting the following error

> Fatal error:  Cannot use 'Void' as class name as it is reserved in /va
>   r/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Voi
>   d.php on line 9
>
> My php version is  7.0.20-2

also while placing an order I'm getting following error

> An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again

Can any one help me to resolve this ?

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix it:

1. Edit `vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/webapi.xml` line 112:

   ```
   - <route url="/V1/invoices/:id/void" method="POST">
   + <route url="/V1/invoices/:id/voidInvoice" method="POST">
   ```
2. Edit `vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/View.php` line 242:

   ```
   - return $this->getUrl('sales/*/void', ['invoice_id' => $this->getInvoice()->getId()]);
   + return $this->getUrl('sales/*/voidInvoice', ['invoice_id' => $this->getInvoice()->getId()]);
   ```
3. Edit `vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/View.php` line 183:

   ```
   - return $this->getUrl('sales/*/void', ['creditmemo_id' => $this->getCreditmemo()->getId()]);
   + return $this->getUrl('sales/*/voidCreditmemo', ['creditmemo_id' => $this->getCreditmemo()->getId()]);
   ```
4. Edit `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Void.php` line 9:

   ```
   - class Void extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice\View
   + class VoidInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice\View
   ```
5. Edit `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/Void.php` line 10:

   ```
   - class Void extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
   + class VoidCreditmemo extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
   ```
6. Rename

   `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/Void.php`

   to

   `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/VoidCreditmemo.php`
7. Rename

   `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Void.php`

   to

   `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/VoidInvoice.php`

taken from https://mage2.pro/t/topic/2433/2

**Note:** It is always recommended to copy files from vendor folder to app/code area and then work on them to prevent issues while upgrading Magento.

Comment: how can i create or re-write these file inside app/code can you give an example i'm little bit confused about re-writing code in vendor files. i need to rewrite this file in code folder "vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/webapi.xml"

Comment: Copy webapi.xml file from **`vendor/magento/module-sales/etc`** folder and put it under **`app/code/Magento_Sales/etc`** folder.

Comment: @ Mohit Kumar Arora so we are using "Magento_Sales " insted of "module-sales" is it?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @ Mohit Kumar Arora do i need to make a new module for this?

Comment: No, there is no need to create a new module for this.

Comment: ok I will try this and update you

Comment: Where i need to do the 6 th and 7th step in my local or vrndore file?

Comment: am i on the right path /app/code/Magento_Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice

Comment: No, the path should be app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice ...

Sorry for typo mistake in my previous comment.

Comment: @ Mohit Kumar Arora  after running this still i got this error " Cannot use 'Void' as class name as it is reserved in /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Void.php on line 9"

Comment: can you answer for this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186141/website-switching-in-magento-1-9-without-changing-the-default-url

Answer (score 0):

I think its usefull for you

I had same problem before, that time I used **php version  7.1.X**, I reduced Php version **7.1.X to php 7.0.8** its works fine for me

Magento 2.1. System requirement http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: but my php version is 7.0.2

Comment: @Amith You mentioned  php -7.0.20.

Comment: @ Rajkumar .E ya i have alredy mentioned it but you say about php version 7.1.X,

Comment: @Amith Yes, when I got error using php 7.1.X,  not php7.0.X.  But I got same error before.

Comment: .Ev in my case i have checked php version using phpinfo function and i got this my version is not 7.1 then why i get this error

Comment: honestly don't know

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rename the vendor and run composer update.