# Website switching in magento 1.9 without changing the default url

Tags: magento-1.9, url, multi-website, store-switcher

I have a website in Magento 1.9 called www.example.com. In Magento, we know that we can create multiple websites so I have created like that multiple websites with their own store and store view. so I have the site.

```
example.com(default)
example.com(2)
example.com(3)
example.com(4)
```

My requirement is I need to switch to these websites by staying the same URL (www.example.com). Can any one help me to do this?

Comment: Without changing the URL, how can you imagine multiple websites?

Comment: @ Mohit Kumar Arora in magento backend how we switching to website the same method i'm asking for

Comment: For the front end, multiple websites mean different session and different URL per website. I don't think multiple websites can be served from a single URL in frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments i have found the solution.You can pass the website code in get parameter and on the basis of that code run the website in index.php. This way your url will not be changed and also set a session for website code.

```
if (isset($_GET["website"])){
   $web=$_GET['website'];
}

if($web=="clt")
{
   $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? 
   $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'clt';
   $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';
   Mage::run('clt', 'website');
}
```

Comment: Great adarsh....